# How to ssh a server via a security http proxy?

Tags: ssh, proxy

i want to ssh the server via a security http proxy whth command like this:

`ssh -o ProxyCommand="nc -X connect -x http_proxy:port -P username %h %p" username@server`

the command will prompt me type password:

`Proxy password for username@http_proxy:`

but nothing happened after my type.

who know the problem in my commands? thx!

Comment: you can add `-v`'s to your `ssh` command to see debug output.  I've done the `nc` proxy command myself, but hard for me to guess what the issue is without more info.

Comment: i add -v to the command , it shows the ssh executing proxy command.@thankyour

Comment: From @tzdunek answer that will probably be deleted. Maybe proxy works fine, but you need to adjust some target connection config, try adding port to ssh, `ssh -p <custom port> home_user@my_home_IP`.